# RaphaelJS : Stop drag when image out of frame

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

i have a RaphaelJS paper which has a set that contains an image and other elements. The Image is larger than the paper, and the user can drag it around. 
However i want the drag to stop so that the image border is never visible, meaning that the user will not the the white margins. I have tried several ways but i keep getting weird results and i cant wrap my head around it.
I can get the top left corner of the image and the remaining corners of the image with calculation. Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE : i have added a** [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8pzcawoy/53/)

*In the example i have added a condition that's supposed to keep the top left cornet outside the canvas, but as you can see there are a lot of glitches and bugs with this.*

[here is an image illustrating the desired result](http://postimg.org/image/jfzwnamzz/)

Code :

```
Raphael.st.draggable = function(index) {
    var me = this,
            lx = 0,
            ly = 0,
            ox = 0,
            oy = 0,
            moveFnc = function(dx, dy) {
                x = set.getBBox().x;
                y = set.getBBox().y;
                console.log(x+":"+y);
                lx = dx + ox;
                ly = dy + oy;
                if(x+dx < 0 && y+dy < 0)//REMOVE THIS CONDITION FOR FREE DRAG
                    me.transform(',,320,240,'+'t' + lx + ',' + ly);

        },
        startFnc = function() {},
        endFnc = function() {
            ox = lx;
            oy = ly;
        };
    this.drag(moveFnc, startFnc, endFnc);
    };
width = 640;
height = 480;
paper = Raphael(cur_id, width, height),

image = paper.image('http://edwardtufte.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Thinking%20Eye/ParisMap.gif', 0, 0,950,805)
set = paper.set();
set.push(image);
paper.canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"
set.draggable();
```

Comment: I would try and get an example on a jsfiddle

Comment: @Ethan, how can there be picture size bigger than paper? and the fiddle has some error, please check.

Comment: There was some problem with JSFiddle importing scripts. I have added the scripts manually and the example now works, you will understand by what i mean picture size is bigger than the paper. https://jsfiddle.net/8pzcawoy/53/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for correctly, it looks like you're only missing the limiting part in your moveFnc drag event.

Something like this in place of your lx and ly assignments should limit the image to be scrollable only to the edges:

```
           if (dx + ox <= 0){
                if (dx + ox > width - image.attrs.width){
                    lx = dx + ox;
                }
                else{
                    lx = width - image.attrs.width;
                }
            }
            if (dy + oy <= 0){
                if (dy + oy > height - image.attrs.height){
                    ly = dy + oy;
                }
                else{
                    ly = height - image.attrs.height;
                }
            }
```

Positive translation will allow the image to drag to the left and down. If we limit the translation to negative values, it will stop at the left and top edges.  For the right and bottom edges, we limit the negative translation to values bigger than the width of the paper minus the width of the image.